# jquery flot how to make tick size not time

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using ticksize in jquery.

this is my code:

```
 chartOptions = {
               xaxis: {
                   min: (new Date(2011, 11, 15)).getTime(),
                   //max: (new Date(2012, 04, 18)).getTime(),
                   max: maxData,
                   mode: "time",
                   tickSize: [1, "month"],
                   monthNames: dataNames,
                   tickLength: 0
               },
```

#### is there another mode than time?

I worked so hard to make the chart dynamic but I couldn't success because the tickzie is always in month.

#### my situation

I have many agents. and I want to make one bar for each agent.

what is the ticksize should be? I hope it is in numbers.

help please. if there is any documenation please.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking.  What do you mean when you hope that tickSize is in numbers?  Could you provide a sample of what you're looking for?

Comment: @DNS I mean. I need to use other mode that `time`. I need a mode that is taking numbers like `1` to `10`

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make much sense, but here goes. You say you want numbers instead of months, but your options specifically configure flot to use time. So, don't use the options you posted.

```
    $.plot("#placeholder",data, {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.3,
                align: "center",
            }
        }
    });
```

[Here's a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/k9FkZ/6/) of a bar chart.